# Merging or Linking Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request

There are very [strong rumours](http://arstechnica.co.uk/apple/2016/04/apple-os-x-becoming-macos-rebrand/) that Apple will be rebranding OSX to macOS in June 2016.

Would it be a good idea to merge [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) tags with [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) ahead of time? Or at the very least link the two terms somehow?

Comment: Until it happens or it is confirmed by Apple, I don't see the rush, we shouldn't merge the tags without also looking at the questions that use them.  In other words there is no reason to rush the merger.

Comment: This may have been missed and reposted because the title doesn't provide a clue.  I'll vote to link this one as a dupe per the comment on the newer one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) [already has](https://superuser.com/tags/osx/synonyms) [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) as a synonym (established in 2013). If OSX does get official renamed to macOS, we would want to reverse the synonym direction. That would require a moderator because there are vastly more questions tagged with [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) at the moment.

I support the synonymization, but we should wait until the change is official. (It would be pretty awkward to have to undo the link.) If there are strong, credible sources for the rumors, tag wiki edits could be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a natural fit, though I'd want the rumour to be confirmed, and some flavour of community consensus for merging the tags. *Unmerging* tags can be a pain so some degree of official confirmation would be essential too.