# Am told I cannot create tag - I am not trying to create a tag

Tags: support, bug

Trying to change my question

https://superuser.com/questions/1161441/chrome-switches-tab-unexpectedly-with-a-noise

to

> OS: Mac OSX 10.12.2 Browser: Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)
>
> I am in one tab - for example writing a comment or answer in
>   StackOverflow  when out of the blue with a tweety sound,
>   "chrome://apps" page replaces the page I am on.
>
> Is it some kind of key/mouse/swipe combo I have not noticed that I do
>   with my magic mouse?

on a bountied question, I am told I need 300 points to create the tag macos - I am doing no such thing.

Please help me update my question

[image]

Comment: See also http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11501/merging-or-linking-tags

Comment: It's been fixed. And I've edited the question for you. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a tag synonym that got [reversed earlier today](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12014/os-x-macos-tag-synonyms-should-be-reversed) is the cause.

New edits to questions will trigger the synonym rename and, as the existing tag has no questions, fail with the warning you are seeing.

For now I have retagged your question with [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) and as a side effect created the tag in question.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [macos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) does not exist. It is, however, a synonym of the tag [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx). OSX and macOS are functionally the same hence the tag association.